# convertView.FindViewById returns null in adapter.GetView

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm trying to display a list of log items in an android app, however whenever I call convertView.FindViewByID, I get a NullReferenceException. The layout inflates properly with the correct amount of child views according to the debugger, but I cannot get any of the child views using FindViewById.

My solution is spread over a couple of projects, but both the adapter (and containing view) and the layout are in the same project. This project is not the startup project, but this hasn't been a problem so far.

I've made sure that I'm referencing the correct layout file, I've checked that the layout isn't improperly formed to the best of my knowledge, and I've double-checked the IDs and types of the views I'm referencing. It all looks correct.

I've also checked about 3-4 pages of search results on Google, full of answers to similar questions, but none of them working for me. I do not have access to an OnFinishInflate method, and I've made absolutely sure that it's the correct layout and that the IDs are correct. I've also checked to make sure that no IDs are duplicates. The layout doesn't exist anywhere else in the solution, and none of the IDs in the layout file exist anywhere else either. Essentially, from what I've found, the other solutions are either things I'm already doing, or not applicable because I'm doing this in an adapter's GetView method, not in a fragment or activity.

The list of items to display populates properly, and has the expected number and type of items.

Here's the GetView method:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.startLogListItem, null, false);
            }

            var log = _logsEntries[position];

            var image = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.startLogListItem_imageView1); //returns null
            image.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.icon_info); //throws NullReferenceException

            convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.startLogListItem_txtMessage).Text = log.Name;
            convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.startLogListItem_txtDateTime).Text = log.Date.ToShortTimeString();
            convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.startLogListItem_txtTimespan).Text = log.Duration.ToReadableShortString();

            return convertView;

        }
```

And here's the contents of the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/startLogListItem.imageView1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
            <TextView
                android:text="Label Label Label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/startLogListItem.txtMessage" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
            <TextView
                android:text="17.35"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#393939"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/startLogListItem.txtDateTime"
                android:paddingRight="20dp" />
            <TextView
                android:text="17.35"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#393939"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/startLogListItem.txtTimespan" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Whenever I call convertView.FindViewById, it returns null and any attempted assignment to one of the subviews throws a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the cause of the problem and solve it.

The problem was in the ID, but not in a way that I expected, or even knew could be an issue. The problem was that the ID started with a lower case letter, not an upper case letter. Changing from a lower case to an upper case letter fixed the issue. For one reason or another, a lower case "s" doesn't work, but a lower case "a" is fine. I initially suspected this might be related to the limit on IDs, but we're nowhere near the roughly 65000 limit on resources for IDs.

But in any case, changing the first letter to a capital S fixed the issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

The id in layout including `.` is not valid, you can try to replace the `.` to `_`
For example,

replace

```
  android:id="@+id/startLogListItem.txtMessage"
```

with

```
 android:id="@+id/startLogListItem_txtMessage"
```

The same is true for other ids that contain `.`.

Comment: This was incredibly close to the correct answer. You're absolutely right that periods aren't valid, and we discovered that about 20 minutes before you posted your answer. Unfortunately, underscores don't appear to be valid either. At least, it's giving the same error. When changing the ID to be much shorter, however, it works. Simply removing the period wasn't enough either, so right now I'm guessing it might have something to do with the ID length.

Comment: Nevermind, turns out that the first letter of the ID had to be an upper case letter, not a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see you have to two seprate id's the one in xml:

```
android:id="@+id/startLogListItem.imageView1"
```

And the one that you are searching for:

```
convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.startLogListItem_imageView1);
```

When they match it should work!!!

Comment: This is because the first ID is turned into the second ID when the Resources file is generated. Even if the first ID matched the second exactly, I still get the error. Periods in the ID are turned into underscores when the resources file is generated. I've done this in multiple other places in the project, and it works in all of those places. Unfortunately, this is not the problem. For good measure, I tried changing the ID in the layout file, and it still produced the same error. Visual Studio would also have marked that as an error after compiling if this was the issue.

Comment: Did you check the childs for the convertView? is your image present?

Comment: The convertView has 2 children, as expected from the layout. I can't check exactly what the children are, at least I haven't found a way to do that yet. The image is present, yes. The image definitely isn't the problem. If I comment out the image lines, I get the same NullReferenceException when trying to set the text of the textviews.